# fatal error: 'bpf_helper_defs.h' file not found

Tags: testing, linux-kernel

When I run `make kselftest-install`, it shows the following error:

> ../../../lib/bpf/bpf_helpers.h:11:10: fatal error: 'bpf_helper_defs.h'
> file not found

How to solve this issue? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to find the missing file in your kernel source code root directory.

```
$ find -name bpf_helper_defs.h
./tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/libbpf/include/bpf/bpf_helper_defs.h
./tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/libbpf/bpf_helper_defs.h
```

It shows that bpf_helper_defs.h exists, but in a different directory than bpf_helpers.h locates. So a simple way to solve this issue is to copy the missing file to the same directory.

```
$ cp ./tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/libbpf/include/bpf/bpf_helper_defs.h ./tools/lib/bpf/
```

Run `make kselftest-install` again, the error disappears.